# Twisted-17.9.0-cp27-cp27m-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this pl

Tags: python-3.x, twisted

i use `python` `3.6`

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip install d:\Twisted-17.9.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

`Twisted-17.9.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl` is not a supported wheel on this platfor
m.

what I should do?

Comment: Erm... use the one for 3.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wheel you have is for Python 3.7.  The version number is encoded in the filename - "cp37-cp37m".  You need to get "cp36-cp36m".  Or let Pip select the correct version by just running `pip install twisted`.